# I need to perform a query in MySQL that joins two queries that I performed in just one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to perform a MySQL query that returns the number of projects (COD_PROJETO) and adds the total subscription value (VALOR_TOTAL_ASSIN), per subscriber (COD_SUBSCRIBE) all in the same query.

I can make these queries separately, as shown below, but I need them in the same query.

QUANTITY OF PROJECTS:

```
SELECT COUNT(COD_PROJETO) AS QTD_PROJETOS
FROM DIM_PROJETOS ;
```

TOTAL AMOUNT PER SUBSCRIBER:

```
SELECT COD_ASSINANTE,SUM(VALOR_TOTAL_ASSIN) AS VLR_TOT
FROM TAB_ASSINATURAS
GROUP BY COD_ASSINANTE;
```

I need the above two results, in the same query.
Also follows the creation of tables with the data inserted:

```
CREATE TABLE DIM_PROJETOS(COD_PROJETO INT, REVISTA VARCHAR(100), EDITORA VARCHAR(3), TIPO_REVISTA VARCHAR(50));

CREATE TABLE TAB_ASSINATURAS(COD_ASSINANTE INT, COD_PROJETO INT, VIGENCIA INT, QT_PARCELAS INT, VALOR_TOTAL_ASSIN FLOAT);

INSERT INTO DIM_PROJETOS VALUES(837, "MINHA CASA", "EDA", "IMPRESSA");
INSERT INTO DIM_PROJETOS VALUES(838, "MAXIMA", "CAR", "IMPRESSA");
INSERT INTO DIM_PROJETOS VALUES(847, "ELLE DIGITAL", "EDA", "DIGITAL");
INSERT INTO DIM_PROJETOS VALUES(873, "CLAUDIA DIGITAL", "EDA", "DIGITAL");
INSERT INTO DIM_PROJETOS VALUES(883, "VEJA DIGITAL + ONLINE", "EDA", "DIGITAL");
INSERT INTO DIM_PROJETOS VALUES(884, "QUADRINHOS DISNEY", "EDA", "IMPRESSA");

INSERT INTO TAB_ASSINATURAS VALUES(1001, 837, 13, 1, 145.60);
INSERT INTO TAB_ASSINATURAS VALUES(1001, 901, 6, 1, 58.98);
INSERT INTO TAB_ASSINATURAS VALUES(1001, 907, 42, 12, 315);
INSERT INTO TAB_ASSINATURAS VALUES(1002, 847, 28, 1,373.40 );
INSERT INTO TAB_ASSINATURAS VALUES(1002, 873, 12, 12, 133.20);
INSERT INTO TAB_ASSINATURAS VALUES(1002, 893, 12, 1, 86.72);
INSERT INTO TAB_ASSINATURAS VALUES(1003, 905, 36, 18, 508.67);
INSERT INTO TAB_ASSINATURAS VALUES(1004, 901, 36, 18, 216);
```

Below is an image of the tables(Note, they have no relationship.):[image]

Comment: Could you please show the expected outcome?

Comment: Why do you need to obtain **non-related** data (which contradicts **relational** database term) in single query? Moreover, the data which you need in is a data of different aggregation level, and its combining into solid rowset produces duplicated data and is not logical.

Comment: PS. https://dbfiddle.uk/DDGOkagO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cross join the two queries.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(COD_PROJETO) AS QTD_PROJETOS
    FROM DIM_PROJETOS
) AS q1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT COD_ASSINANTE,SUM(VALOR_TOTAL_ASSIN) AS VLR_TOT
    FROM TAB_ASSINATURAS
    GROUP BY COD_ASSINANTE
) AS q2
```

Comment: yes, i managed to do this way, but this is in T-SQL, I want to know how to do this cross join in MySQL.

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work in MySQL.

Comment: Because there is no cross apply clause in MySQL.

Comment: @JonJon This doesn't use CROSS APPLY, it uses CROSS JOIN, which does exist in MySQL.

Comment: You're right, sorry @Barmar, it worked here.

Thank you so much!!!